# How do I return only file names from the find command?

Tags: mac, terminal, find

I'm looking to get a list of just file names (without the rest of the path) when executing the find command from a terminal. How do I accomplish this on the mac?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

With basename:

`find . -type f -exec basename {} \;`

Comment: What are curly braces for?

Comment: basename is run once for every found file, denoted by {}.

Comment: what is the mean of the \ and ;  ?

Comment: @neouyghur `;` terminates the `-exec` action. The `\ ` is needed because `;` also has special meaning to the shell.

Answer (score 7):

Evilsoup mentioned that what was posted doesn't work for spaced file names.  So instead you could use:

```
find . -type f -print0 | while IFS= read -r -d '' filename; do echo ${filename##*/}; done
```

Comment: This will break on files with spaces in their names (see [parsing ls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) on greg's wiki)

Comment: +1 for speed. I don't know if I did something wrong, but this one took 1 second on my $HOME, whereas all others took around 10 seconds. Of course, I would need more than 10 seconds to look this up and type it.

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT**:

Using `sed`:

```
$ find . -type f | sed 's/.*\///'
```

---

Using the [xargs](http://linux.die.net/man/1/xargs) command, as mentioned in the response of @nerdwaller

```
$ find . -type f -print0 | xargs --null -n1 basename
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing that one out, +1, I haven't used xargs much... Definitely should since you dropped quite a few characters off my command.

Comment: This one breaks when files have spaces. It works like this, at least in a quick test: `find . -type f -print0| xargs --null -n1 basename`

Comment: Neither of `--null` or `-n1` options is available on OSX

Answer (score 2):

With GNU find, you can do:

```
 find ~/tmp/ -printf "%f\n"
```

This is probably worth trying in OS X too.

Comment: `-printf` isn't supported on OS X's BSD `find`.

Comment: Also, `-printf` bears little relation to the C `printf` or the POSIX shell utility `printf`. Using this historic function name for something different is very poorly considered. The conservative BSD guys likely see it the same way, so we won't probably won't see clone of `-printf` in the BSD find, under that name.

Comment: I disagree that it's poorly considered to use a familiar function name to perform a similar task in a different context. Why BSD will probably never support it is another matter.

Answer (score 2):

There is a better way to strip everything but the last portion of a file path; with awk. It is better because awk is not executed once for every file. In some cases this matters.

```
find ~/tmp/ -type f  | awk -F/ '{ print $NF }'
```

We look only for files in ~/tmp and we get a list where every entry is separated by slashes. Hence, we use a slash as the field separator (-F/) and print the field parameter ($1..$9) that corresponds to the last field ($NF).

Comment: This is the fastest I tested.

Comment: I've been using Cygwin lately, and creating a process in windows is super expensive...

Answer (score 1):

You can call `sh` from within find's `-exec` option and avoid using uneccesary pipes. This also has the advantage that you don't need to worry about funny filenames (spaces, newlines, etc.):

```
find . -type f -exec sh -c 'echo "${0##*/}"' {} \;
```

Answer (score 1):

What about this:

```
find … | egrep -o -e '[^/]+$'
```

Advantage: Only exactly one additional process is spawned, not one for each result.